# React views in nested navigators become unresponsive to taps / touch

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am developing an Expo managed React Native app, and have a Bottom Tab navigator nested inside a stack navigator. I'm using React Navigation. The tab navigator in itself has a nested stack navigator. The structure is as follows:

```
- Stack navigator in App.js
   - Stack navigator
   - Bottom Tab navigator with 3 tabs 
     - Tab 1: Basic view component 
     - Tab 2: Stack navigator
     - Tab 3: Stack navigator
```

The issue I am running into is that the Bottom Tab Navigator view becomes unresponsive to taps on TouchableOpacity elements. Scrolling the view still works, but nothing else (e.g. I am unable to navigate away from the page, open a modal etc).

The curious part is that this issue will persist for a while, and then disappear. If I wait on the unresponsive screen, it will eventually trigger the taps that it didn't respond to at first.

Anyone here run into a similar issue in the past?

Comment: Show your structure what you've done till now.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a somewhat clone of what you want.

See working example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/nested-navigator-structure) in this Snack.

According to that my `AppNavigator.js` looked like this -

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import TabScreenOne from '../screens/TabScreenOne';
import TabScreenTwo from '../screens/TabScreenTwo';
import TabScreenThree from '../screens/TabScreenThree';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import CollectionsScreen from '../screens/CollectionsScreen';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

const InnerStack = createStackNavigator();

function InnerStackFNC() {
  return (
    <InnerStack.Navigator>
      <InnerStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <InnerStack.Screen
        name="CollectionsScreen"
        component={CollectionsScreen}
      />
    </InnerStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="TabOne" component={TabScreenOne} />
      <Tab.Screen name="TabTwo" component={TabScreenTwo} />
      <Tab.Screen name="TabThree" component={TabScreenThree} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator>
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="InnerStack"
        component={InnerStackFNC}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

Then in my `App.js`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import AppMavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppMavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I already have this laid out. The issue is that a subview stops responding to touch gestures.

Comment: Can you tell the `subview` of which `screen` stops responding??